# mvn dependency:analyze usage

Tags: java, maven, plugins, dependencies

Is it still good practice handling your dependencies so that

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

does not show any warning ?

it complains when code is explicitly using dependency wothout it being declared, or in case code is not using a declared dependency

For the latter case I can think of more than a couple of scenarios when
we actually need to have "unused" dependencies.

But for the first case, should we always make sure we have no warnings ?

Answer (score 0):

There are exceptions where you need an artifact as dependency, but it is not "used" in the classical sense by your source code. In this case, you can define an exception by settings the `<ignoredDependencies>` parameter for `dependency:analyze`.

Answer (score -1):

it's used to find out dependencies which are not used in your project. In other words, you may have had added some dependencies to your project in the development phase but eventually, you do not have any use for those in your code. this command helps you to find and remove them to have a lighter jar file.